# Entity Framework Code First: Doesn't load referenced object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have a problem with a simple class. One property of my class is a reference to another class, but when I read, it's always null.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Trademark Trademark { get; set; }
}

public class Trademark
{
    public int TrademarkId { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

Those are my classes, very simple.
Then when I get the first element:

```
Product p = context.Products.First();
```

And `p` contains the right product, but Trademark is null.

Even if I want to do a query using linq, like:

```
var prods = context.Products.Where(p => p.Trademark.TrademarkId == 1).ToList();
```

The database is generated Ok.

Using EF 4.3.1, with SqlServer compact edition 4.0

Thanks for any suggestions.

Add: This is my context class:

```
public class HPContext : DbContext
{
    public HPContext()
        : base()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; //Just for test

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Trademark> Trademarks { get; set; }  

}
```

Add: Database schema:

```
Table: 
  Products

Fields: 
  Id int primaryKey
  Description nvarchar(4000)
  Trademark_TrademarkId int


Table:
  Trademarks

Fields:
  TrademarkId int PrimaryKey
  Description nvarchar(4000)
```

Comment: Could you provide database schema? Apparently problem with associations...

Comment: Ok, i'll in my home in one hour and post the database... however, the database is generated with ef.

Comment: i could log to my computer and get the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shall use `Include` to include navigation properties if lazy loading is not enabled;

```
Product p = context.Products.Include("TradeMark").First();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got and exception: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Product' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Trademark'.

Comment: Sorry, i make a mistake, i re-tried with "Trademark" and works. is there any other simpler way? Because product will have several references?. Thanks

Comment: @Gabriel, you may enable lazy loading.